# How to override View & Template

Tags: openstack-horizon

I m checking horizon documentation at docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/.
what I am trying to do is to add more information on volumn detail page.  I want create that page as tabbed page, show the current information as well as new information.  Add tab, which will refreshed with regular interval.

My question is Can I do that without changing openstack code & by extending. If yes, then how can I do that.  I dont want code here, but some guidance on how I am creating tab & moving existing info in one tab.

Thanks
Aniruddha

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar for loadbalancers panel where we wanted to modify some existing tabs and also add couple of new tabs. Also, we wanted to make our changes available as a PIP package that anyone could install easily.

Checkout the repository available at https://github.com/avinetworks/avi-horizon-dashboard/

The README describes the changes users have to make in their local_settings.py to get this new code included into horizon.

Particularly, check this file that has code to weave in the code from this package into the existing horizon code:
[https://github.com/avinetworks/avi-horizon-dashboard/blob/master/avidashboard/dashboards/project/**init**.py](https://github.com/avinetworks/avi-horizon-dashboard/blob/master/avidashboard/dashboards/project/__init__.py)

Comment: I saw your code, but not make much of it. Currently, I am still exploring horizon.  My requirement is. For volume detail page, currently there is no tab.  I want to have there 2 tabs. Current information, move to first tab & on second tab get some information from other api